# How to change validates_numericality_of into validate on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

How do I change

```
validates_numericality_of :test, :greater_than_or_equal_to=>0
```

into validate form

I tried only character and nil values. I need to check also it must be greater than 0

```
validate change_test

def change_test
  if @test.nil?
     errors.add_to_base('Hi Test should be only number')
  end
end
```

and also I tried like this,

```
validate change_test

def change_test
  if @test.nil?
     errors.add_to_base('Hi Test should be only number')
  else
    if @test < 0
     errors.add_to_base('The number should be greater than or equal to 0')
    end
  end
end
```

but it is result in error

Please help to solve this problem

***thanks all***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give the error message, it's a lot easier to diagnose the problem.
2. Use built in validations, learn how to change their messages (`:message` parameter to `validates_numericality_of`)
3. `if @test < 0` should rather be `if @test.to_i` < 0

Comment: if i use built in validations, the field name also coming along with the error message

examples
test: is not valid

i don't want test: to be displayed
so i turned towards user defined validate

Comment: and the error is undefined method `to_i' for #<Money:0xb57d1e90>

Comment: It seems that you are calling to_i on the Money object instead on the test attribute of a Money object.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your code need to be changed to:

```
validate :change_test

def change_test
  if test.nil?
     errors.add_to_base('Hi Test should be only number')
  end
end
```

There are 2 problem with your code:

1. The validate method need to use symbol as the parameter.

2. I am assuming test is the attribute, you should not use @ symbol.

So for the last part of the code, it should be:

```
class Money < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :change_test

  # We are validating an attribute of the Money model called test
  def change_test
    # This is to test for nil value which is empty string
    if test.blank?
      errors.add_to_base('Hi Test value cannot be empty')
    end

    # This is to make sure value is greater than or equal to 0
    if test.to_i < 0
      errors.add_to_base('The number should be greater than or equal to 0')
    end
  end

end
```

Please note that test is **not** an object. It is an attribute in the model class.

I hope this helps.

Comment: the problem still arises,

local variable and instance variable acting same here